# Unable to get table output with stargazer in Rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, stargazer

I tried to present my regression table on R markdown and I had even added the results='asis' to the R code chunk but he final result is still the latex code from the stargazer output and not the table

````
```{r, results='asis'}
  stargazer(lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars), header=FALSE)
```
````

and my output was

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}}lc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textit{Dependent variable:}} \\ 
\cline{2-2} 
\\[-1.8ex] & mpg \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 wt & $-$5.344$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (0.559) \\ 
  & \\ 
 Constant & 37.285$^{***}$ \\ 
  & (1.878) \\ 
  & \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
Observations & 32 \\ 
R$^{2}$ & 0.753 \\ 
Adjusted R$^{2}$ & 0.745 \\ 
Residual Std. Error & 3.046 (df = 30) \\ 
F Statistic & 91.375$^{***}$ (df = 1; 30) \\ 
\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\textit{Note:}  & \multicolumn{1}{r}{$^{*}$p$<$0.1; $^{**}$p$<$0.05; $^{***}$p$<$0.01} \\ 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

which was the latex code. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Stargazer outputs latex by default. You can vary the output format by `type`.

From `?stargazer`

> ```
> type: a character vector that specifies what type of output the
>       command should produce. The possible values are ‘"latex"’
>       (default) for LaTeX code, ‘"html"’ for HTML/CSS code,
>       ‘"text"’ for ASCII text output.
> ```

```
>stargazer(lm(mpg ~ wt, data=mtcars), header=FALSE, type='text')


===============================================
                        Dependent variable:
                    ---------------------------
                                mpg
-----------------------------------------------
wt                           -5.344***
                              (0.559)

Constant                     37.285***
                              (1.878)

-----------------------------------------------
Observations                    32
R2                             0.753
Adjusted R2                    0.745
Residual Std. Error       3.046 (df = 30)
F Statistic           91.375*** (df = 1; 30)
===============================================
Note:               *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Comment: How would you fix the issue if you wanted the table to be a nice pdf latex format in stead of text format though? It should make a table when knitted to pdf with results='asis' in the chunk options but it does not

Comment: just add replace `type='text'` with `type='latex'`. OP's question was on how to avoid latex output